# Displacing character vertically without affecting line breaks

Tags: luatex, positioning, line-spacing, marginnote

I'm trying to set up margin notes with [manicules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manicule). I'd like to use the actual unicode character for a manicule, and I'd like to have it offset to the left of the rest of the note, enlarged, and shifted down somewhat so it points to the correct line as shown here.
[image: Picture of the desired results. Manicule is separated from the margin note, and the margin note line breaks are all even.]
Right now I have the following code, which is close to what I want, but the enlarged and shifted manicule is causing a large line break.

```
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[hmarginratio={1:3},totalwidth={4.5in},marginparwidth={13em},marginparsep={3em},vmargin=1in]{geometry}

[...]

\lettrine{\red{B}}{eginning of document}
    In this example I want the manicule to be pointing at the end of this line.

\marginnote{\raisebox{-1em}{\llap{\fontspec{AppleSymbols}\huge{☜}}}\lipsum[5-5]}
\lipsum[1-4]
```

which outputs
[image: Same as last picture but with a large line break after the first line of the margin note]

So my question is either how do I have latex ignore the manicule character when making line breaks for the rest of the margin note. Or is there an overall better way of achieving this result.

I'm using LuaLaTex in TexStudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only use the symbol in that context, you can shorten your input using `\newunicodechar`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[
  hmarginratio={1:3},
  totalwidth={4.5in},
  marginparwidth={13em},
  marginparsep={3em},
  vmargin=1in
]{geometry}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newfontface{\symbolsfont}{AppleSymbols}[Scale=1.8]
\newunicodechar{☜}{%
  \raisebox{-0.5ex}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\symbolsfont ☜}\ignorespaces
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\lettrine{B}{eginning of document}
In this example I want the manicule to be pointing at the end of this line.
\marginnote{☜\lipsum[5][1-2]}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Avoid using `\fontspec` in the document body, it's slow and inefficient.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by putting the rest of the margin note in its own parbox, which is aligned to the top of the previous text with [t].

```
    \marginnote{\raisebox{-1em}{\llap{\fontspec{AppleSymbols}\huge{☜}}}{\parbox[t]{13em}{\lipsum[5-5]}}}
```

[image: same pic as in question but fixed]